# How to Define that a Type T must have a field "ID"

Tags: c#, .net, generics

This sample:

```
public static void createDictionary<T>(IEnumerable<T> myRecords)
            where T: T.ID // Wont Compile
        {
            IDictionary<int, T> dicionario = myRecords.ToDictionary(r => r.ID);


            foreach (var item in dicionario)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}",item.Key);

                Type thisType = item.Value.GetType();

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var itemField in thisType.GetProperties())
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", itemField.Name, itemField.GetValue(item.Value, null)));
                }

                Console.WriteLine(sb);
            }

        }
```

how can I force the type passed as parameter has a field called "ID"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create an interface:

```
public interface IWithID
{
    // For your method the set(ter) isn't necessary
    // public int ID { get; set; } 
    public int ID { get; }
}

public static void createDictionary<T>(IEnumerable<T> myRecords)
        where T: IWithID
```

You'll need to use a property, not a field in this way.

Or clearly you could use a base type...

```
public abstract class WithID
{
    // public int ID; // non readonly
    public readonly int ID; // can even be a field
}

public static void createDictionary<T>(IEnumerable<T> myRecords)
        where T: WithID
```

Another solution is to pass a delegate:

```
public static void createDictionary<T>(IEnumerable<T> myRecords, 
                                       Func<T, int> getID)
```

then you use the `GetID` to get the ID, like `myRecords.ToDictionary(getID)`

Comment: I'd suggest making the property read-only rather than read/write; I would very rarely want an ID property to be writable.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was thinking to EF POCO classes

Comment: I was trying to escape to declare a new interface ... I thought there was a solution by the field name... But thanks

Comment: @WilnerAvila The weakness of the restrictions usable on generics is a sad sad thing...

Comment: @WilnerAvila Other solution... Pass a `Func<T, int>` to your method.

Comment: @xanatos yes that works! which one would be a better soluttion for an OOP design in your opinion?

Comment: @WilnerAvila Normally I use the `Func<>` variant for my code, because it's more general (I could modify it to work with a `createDictionary<T, TKey>` method very easily, so I wouldn't be limited to `int` keys. Adding an interface is always something more complex and global. Adding a delegate to a method has much lesser impact.

Comment: hm thats true. How could i do that? this way? *public static void createDictionary<TID, TValue>(IEnumerable<TValue> myRecords, Func<TValue, TID> getID)*

Comment: @WilnerAvila I normally put the `<TValue, TId>` order, but it's the same. Yes.

Comment: @xanatos: Just because the *implementation* has a writable property doesn't mean that the *interface* should.

Comment: I found that in game development, many internal objects are easily stored with an Identifier. I also had many different classes with a string Identifier, and wanted a way to easily implement this across all items. Inheritance was just a stupid idea, but I absolutely love having added a IIdentifiable<T> interface. It just made everything so neat and orderly. And now I can also generically pass around those objects, too, by just treating them as a IIdentifiable<string> or what have you. I wanted to write this here because it may seem simple to most people, but this is seriously a great design.

Answer (score 5):

Inherit it from an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) that has `ID` defined.

```
public interface IIDInterface {
     int ID { get; set; }
}


public static void createDictionary<T>(IEnumerable<T> myRecords)
            where T: IIDInterface
```

Comment: IIdentifiable<T> with a field of T Identifier{get;set;} is a better design, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` syntax is meant to indicate that the class bases some other class. So you'd need a base class:

```
public abstract class IDBaseClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

to then change it to something like this:

```
where T : IDBaseClass
```

Then, the types that you use there just need to base that class. Now, if you can't build an abstract class because your types are already basing something, you can use an interface:

```
public interface IIDInterface
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

and you could change the `where` syntax to be:

```
where T : IIDInterface
```

So then your types that use this generic class just need to implement that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx

you require a "base class" or an "interface" which has the property ID which all the classes implement

```
where T : BaseClassWithID
```

or

```
where T : IInterfaceWithID
```